# Airflow 2.0 timeout exception issue after migration

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have currently migrated to airflow 2 from 1.10 and see the below error:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/wh_braze_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 416, in parent
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/timeout.py", line 37, in handle_timeout
    raise AirflowTaskTimeout(self.error_message)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: DagBag import timeout for /opt/airflow/dags/orders_dag.py after 30.0s, PID: 11866
```

How to resolve this?This does not happen with airflow 1.10 works fine there why time out in 2.0 anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: Please post you DAG code

Comment: might be related to https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#default-value-for-celery-operation_timeout-has-changed-to-10 but the message says broken dag which suggest other wise. please post your dag code and give details about the environment (executor, in what version the code works etc)

Comment: Thanks guys.Its resolved now it was due to kubernetes pod cpu issues it was making metadata connection issues